# How to avoid Fuelphp converting html code to htmlentities

Tags: php, html-entities, fuelphp

I'll like to pass some html code from the controller to the view (as is), but fuelphp automatically converts to html entities so the code is not displayed correctly....
Here is my code:

```
    $data['test_html'] = "<b>Test</b>";
    return Response::forge(View::forge('link/index', $data));
```

In the browser (source code), is displayed like this:

```
&lt;b&gt;Test&lt;/b&gt;
```

Any idea how to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: I saw that I need to put the prep_value to false... but how can I do it? and only with that particular view....

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the auto htmlentity conversion by passing false as third parameter.

```
    return Response::forge(View::forge('link/index', $data, false));
```

> If you want to pass it anyway, you need to use set($name, $value, false)

source: [fuelphp-doc Views](https://fuelphp.com/docs/general/views.html)